# CodeIgniter MySQL update mutiple tables at once db->update() db->where()

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, where-clause, updating

I am using CodeIgniter and want to make a MySQL query that updates multiple tables like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE1, TABLE2
SET 
    TABLE1.NAME='Teddy', 
    TABLE2.CLIENT_NOTES = 'Teddy is a good guy' 
WHERE VISITOR.ID = 1
```

How can I do this using CodeIgniter's **db->update()** and **db->where()**?
Is this possible?

Thanks for having a look at this.
Regards.

Comment: I think its not possible, we need to update one by one.

Comment: why not use native sql, cleaner and readable when onto complex queries

Comment: You mean db->query('mysql code here')? I am trying to make sure I maintain the security and other built in features of codeigniter - Am I defeating these or the purpose of using codeigniter by using "native sql" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use $this->db->query() for something more complex as this

There is no difference as far as escaping, security, etc. Active Record just formats the different strings into a single query string.

Comment: Are we certain about the security being bypassed - I got the feeling that it was - when using db->query()  - after reading this page>>> http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

"Escaping Queries

It's a very good security practice to escape your data before submitting it into your database. CodeIgniter has three methods that help you do this:
$this->db->escape()
"

Comment: Yes, it is fine. What you need to be sure to do is use Query Bindings, which you can read about at the bottom of that page. This automatically escapes, and (helps) prevent injection attacks

$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick')); 

"The secondary benefit of using binds is that the values are automatically escaped, producing safer queries. You don't have to remember to manually escape data; the engine does it automatically for you."

Answer (score 3):

First of all You need to give  alias to your tables like, `table1 as t1` and `table2 as t2` So, your final query will become like this,

```
$this->db->set('t1.row','New value');
$this->db->set('t2.row','New value');
$this->db->where('t1.row','Your Condition');
$this->db->where('t2.row','Your Condition');
$this->db->update('table1 as t1, table2 as t2');
```

Comment: While I using this code:
         $this->db->set('reg.email_hash_code', '');
         $this->db->set('log.password', 'password');
         $this->db->where('reg.email_hash_code','hashcode'); 
         $this->db->where('log.emailid', 'email@gm.com'); 
         $this->db->where('log.user_id = reg.user_id');     

        $this->db->update('jc_login as log, jc_registration as reg');  

I got the foll error :
Table 'databasename .jc_login as log, jc_registration' doesn't exist